# Effects of recursing

Tags: ingress

With Ingress Prime, Niantic offers the ability to "Recurse" for level 16 players.  This apparently involves resetting back to level 1, while keeping some overall benefits (inventory items, recharge distance, mission progression, level-gated services).

Are there any special abilities that recursed players would qualify for?

Comment: Ingress Prime isn't even released yet, so why "offered" past tense?

Comment: Ingress Prime was released over 12 hours ago, @MatthiasUrlichs.
Doesn't explain the past tense though.

Comment: The past tense refers to when it was released.  I'll edit it for clarity.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As of 6 November 2018, Upon Recursion, you experience the following benefits:

- Simulacrum icon indicating your recursion next to agent name on profile

  > [image: e]
- Ability to change your Faction
- Retainment of the following:

  - current codename, Achievements, Mission Badges, Inventory items
  - access to level-gated services: Operation Portal Recon, portal submission, mission creation)
  - Level 16 recharge range
- Separated AP count (after recursion; lifetime)
- Simulacrum medal

  > [image: e]
- Simulacrum symbol and achievement times around repeated Onyx Badge achievements

  > [image: e]
- Onyx anniversary medal when Year 6 arrives

Source: [Ingress Help Center](https://support.ingress.com/hc/en-us/articles/360002076467-Recursion)

Images: [Reddit: Post Recursion Stats](https://www.reddit.com/r/Ingress/comments/9ujolh/post_recursion_stats/)

Comment: I'd like to add that even if recharge range is retained, recharging efficiency is not. We at our local community made test with several recursed agents and recharge efficiency depends of the current level so effectively affecting recharging range since for very far away portals efficiency could drop dramatically.